# Why is a 'Select distinct limit 100' using tmp tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, distinct

I hope someone can teach me why MySQL is using temporary tables on a super simple select with a limit of 100 and how to get it do query more efficiently. I'm running MySQL 5.1.53-community.

The following query should check row by row, save it to memory if it's unique from the other's already selected or skip if it is a repeat. Once results 100 are in memory it should terminate the query and output the result. Instead it goes through every single result, loads them into a temporary table on the hard disk sorts them and pulls the first hundred sorted ascending. It should take a fraction of a second, not several hours.

#### Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `some field` FROM `myTable` LIMIT 100
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT `some field` FROM `myTable` LIMIT 100:
id|select_type|table   |type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows      |Extra
1 |SIMPLE     |myTable | ALL|             |   |       |   |223193820 |Using temporary
```

There's no reason for it to sort anything aside from that's how it's programmed. It only needs to return 100 distinct values which I could do much faster manually parsing the raw text.

If it only needs 100 distinct values it doesn't have to check 220 million rows to make sure that a value isn't duplicated in the 100 rows that it is supposed to return.

Comment: I have moved discussion on this question [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49213/discussion-on-question-by-aunt-jamaima-why-is-a-select-distinct-limit-100-usin). Use that facility for further discussion (if necessary).

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways that `SELECT DISTINCT col FROM ... LIMIT 100` can be performed:

Case 1:  Create a temp table with all rows of `col`, sort it, then peel off the first 100 (de-dupping as it goes).

Case 2:  Build a hash in memory, read `col` putting it into the hash, stop after 100.  (Fast.)

Case 3 (if there is `INDEX(col)`):  Leapfrog through the index.  This effectively takes 100 BTree dives into the index.  (Fast, even if few distinct values.)

Which will it do?  It depends on the version, the data, the existence of an index, etc.  Note that 5.1 is antique; you should plan to upgrade to 5.5, then 5.6, then 5.7.  (8.0 is also available, but not "GA".)  The Optimizer has changed a couple of times in this area, so I cannot say what your version will do.

If you are going to do this for all columns, consider, instead,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col1),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col2),
       ...
    FROM TABLE;
```

(No `LIMIT`.)  This won't give you exactly 100 of each, and it will probably give you only the alphabetically/numerically first several (1024 bytes' worth) of each list, but maybe that is good enough.  It is probably faster than column-by-column.

See also `ANALYSE()` (spelled that way).

Answer (score -3):

The answer is that mysql 5.1 performs DISTINCT as group by and order by actions before truncating the rest of the results. It's designers chose to make it write the full data set of the column to a temp table and then sort them even though you probably don't need it to.

In my opinion it makes DISTINCT fairly worthless because you can just as easily use group by.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *"makes DISTINCT fairly worthless"*. `SELECT DISTINCT <columns> FROM tbl;` is equivalent to `SELECT <columns> FROM tbl GROUP BY <columns> ;` in standard SQL and all SQL products. The implementation details are irrelevant.

Comment: Irrelevant? If a user only needs 100 distinct results there is no reason to go through the whole list of potentially millions of distinct values. What's the point of the redundancy?

Comment: My point is that if DISTINCT is worthless, so is GROUP BY. Your answer suggests that they worth differently ;)

Comment: Distinct is worthless because it is a redundancy of group by. Is that really the reason you marked it down?

Comment: I haven't marked anything. But the suggestion that DISTINCT is worthless makes so sense at all. If you claim that the implementation of DISTINCT in MySQL 5.1 is not fully optimized for the specific case (when there is LIMIt and when there is no index), yeah, I might agree. Still a very corner case that coudl be solved with several ways.

Comment: I suggest that `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` have different semantics, so both should be kept in the language.  The former refers to "getting a list of unique values"; the latter begs for aggregation (sum, count, etc).  It is almost coincidence that some `DISTINCTs` can be _implemented_ via `GROUP BY`.  The Optimizer will do whatever is 'best' in either case.

Comment: @RickJames. I'm really curious to know what DISTINCT does that GROUP BY does not.

Comment: Call it "syntactic sugar", if you like.  When I _read_ a query, `DISTINCT` connotes one thing; `GROUP BY`, another.  (I cringe when I see both in the same `SELECT`; and the "novice alert" warning bells start ringing.)

Comment: Where do you see both in the same query?

Comment: (Not in this thread -- but I have seen it in other questions.)